# How to enable bluetooth on Lenovo G550?

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo

`0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Seems like there is no BT hardware?

TIA

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:04b5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 090c:37b1 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0535 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 2.4GHz 2way RF Mouse Receiver
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0b23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd USB Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn ¦ grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: dmesg | grep -i blue shows no output!

Comment: There is no BT hardware.

Comment: Thanks, have to find other solutions